# PyCharm SFTP Automatic Uploading

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

I am using Pycharm 2016.3 Pro Edition and am remotely editing files on an ec2-instance. I have enabled automatic uploading which, to my understanding, means that any changes I make will not require me to press the "upload" button. However, this does not appear to be the case and I am still required to manually upload files. How might I go about fixing this?

Comment: Does it always need to be uploaded manually or only sometimes? Have you been doing code changes in IDE or also in any external tool?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I am always required to manually upload it.. I've only been doing changes in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to trigger an **automatic upload** manually. Oxymoron, I know. This is because there is no option to manually sync your entire project (my understanding*).

I only had 1 Python interpreter: the remote one. However, I added another random interpreter **just so I can switch and switch back**. Once I switched back, the automatic upload was triggered.

---

*footnotes*

* There is no option to automatically sync folders. I know this because if you close all tabs, all the upload options are disabled. All the buttons are related to individual open files.

[image]